# C# save MD5 of each file in a directory, as well as files in all nested/child/sub directories, to a text file

Tags: c#, hash

I am trying to create a log of all files in a given directory (root directory is `MyGlobals.finalPathForWork`) as well as every file in a child or sub-directory that includes 1) all the files and paths; and 2) an MD5 of each file.

The first part of the code, `MyMethod5`, dealing with file paths works correctly. The problem is doing the same with the MD5s of each of those files. I think the code in `CalculateMD5` should generate the MD5, but I don't know how to return the value/string it gets, for each file, and how to write that to the same text file like `MyMethod5` does.

How do I use that MD5 that gets calculated in `CalculateMD5` and write it to `log.txt` like in `MyMethod5()`?

```
        public static void MyMethod5()
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(file);
                File.AppendAllText(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork + @"\\Log.txt", file + Environment.NewLine);

                CalculateMD5(file);
            }
        }

       public static string CalculateMD5(string filename)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

                    return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it with this, but if you see room for improvement please let me know:

```
    public static void MyMethod5()
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(file);
                File.AppendAllText(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork + @"\\Log.txt", file + Environment.NewLine);
                CalculateMD5(file);
            }
        }

       public static void CalculateMD5(string filename)
        {
            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            string file = filename;
            string output;
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    byte[] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                    output = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
                    File.AppendAllText(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork + @"\\Log.txt", "Hash:" + output + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
```